# Simple webshop solution (Craft Commerce)?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce

I am looking for a simple shopping solution for one of my customers. Since their website is already running with CraftCMS, I am looking if there is any integrated solution available.

However, so far I have found only 3 plugins compatible with Craft3:

- [Stripe Payments](https://enupal.com/craft-plugins/stripe-payments)
- [PayPal Buy Now Button](https://enupal.com/craft-plugins/paypal)
- [Craft Commerce](https://craftcms.com/commerce)

Am I missing one?

Does anyone have experience with one or more of these shop systems?

Right now, Craft Commerce Lite looks the best to me, but I am not sure whether I am overlooking something.

Comment: Tell us about the needs and we might be able to match you up with the right plugin.

Comment: For now really basic: A couple of products, one time purchases, no subscription, perhaps not even customer accounts.

Answer (score 4):

You could use https://snipcart.com/, with the product data populated via Craft fields, for an easy/low-cost solution.

No plugin required for this - although https://superbig.co/plugins/snipcart is in the works for an even tighter integration.

For example see https://www.bernatkleinfoundation.org, here's a screenshot of the product entry used to populate products in Snipcart:

[image]